# Need to transfer multiple files from client to server

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm recently working on a project in which I'm basically making a dropbox clone. The server and client are working fine but I'm having a slight issue. I'm able to transfer a single file from the client to the server but when I try to transfer all the files together it gives me an error after the transfer of the first file so basically my code is only working for a single file. I need to make it work for multiple files. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my code

**Server Code**

```
import socket
import thread
import hashlib

serversock = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname();
port = 9000;
serversock.bind((host,port));
filename = ""
serversock.listen(10);
print "Waiting for a connection....."

clientsocket,addr = serversock.accept() 
print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
while True:
    size = clientsocket.recv(1)
    filesz = clientsocket.recv(1)
    if filesz.isdigit():
        size += filesz
        filesize = int(size)
    else:
        filesize = int(size)    
    print filesize
    for i in range(0,filesize):
        if filesz.isdigit():
            filename += clientsocket.recv(1)
        else:
            filename += filesz
            filesz = "0"
    print filename      
    file_to_write = open(filename, 'wb')
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        #print data
        if not data:
            break
        file_to_write.write(data)
    file_to_write.close()
    print 'File received successfully'
serversock.close()
```

**Client Code**

```
import socket
import os
import thread

s = socket.socket() 
host = socket.gethostname()                           
port = 9000
s.connect((host, port))
path = "C:\Users\Fahad\Desktop"
directory = os.listdir(path)
for files in directory:
    print files  
    filename = files
    size = bytes(len(filename))
    #print size
    s.send(size)
    s.send(filename)
    file_to_send = open(filename, 'rb')
    l = file_to_send.read()
    s.sendall(l)
    file_to_send.close()       
    print 'File Sent'                                              
s.close()
```

**Here's the error that I get**

```
Waiting for a connection.....
Got a connection from ('192.168.0.100', 58339)
13
Betternet.lnk
File received successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 22, in <module>
    filesize = int(size)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several minor issues in your snippet. Maybe you could do something like this?

```
import socket
import thread
import hashlib

serversock = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname();
port = 9000;
serversock.bind((host,port));
filename = ""
serversock.listen(10);
print "Waiting for a connection....."

clientsocket,addr = serversock.accept()
print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
while True:
    size = clientsocket.recv(16) # Note that you limit your filename length to 255 bytes.
    if not size:
        break
    size = int(size, 2)
    filename = clientsocket.recv(size)
    filesize = clientsocket.recv(32)
    filesize = int(filesize, 2)
    file_to_write = open(filename, 'wb')
    chunksize = 4096
    while filesize > 0:
        if filesize < chunksize:
            chunksize = filesize
        data = clientsocket.recv(chunksize)
        file_to_write.write(data)
        filesize -= len(data)

    file_to_write.close()
    print 'File received successfully'
serversock.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import os
import thread

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9000
s.connect((host, port))
path = "blah"
directory = os.listdir(path)
for files in directory:
    print files
    filename = files
    size = len(filename)
    size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) # encode filename size as 16 bit binary
    s.send(size)
    s.send(filename)

    filename = os.path.join(path,filename)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    filesize = bin(filesize)[2:].zfill(32) # encode filesize as 32 bit binary
    s.send(filesize)

    file_to_send = open(filename, 'rb')

    l = file_to_send.read()
    s.sendall(l)
    file_to_send.close()
    print 'File Sent'

s.close()
```

Here the client also sends the size of the file. Both size and filesize are encoded as binary strings (you could do another method). The filename length (size) can take values up to 2^16 and the send file can have up to 2^32 byte (that is 2^filesize).

Comment: What if the filesize is greater than 2^16 bytes? It won't work for that file?

Comment: This is what the server says:
C:\Users\Fahad\Desktop>python server.py
Waiting for a connection.....
Got a connection from ('192.168.0.100', 49349)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 22, in <module>
    filesize = int(filesize, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: 'Betternet.lnk'

Comment: I updated it, now the size of the filename is encoded, too. It should work for longer filenames now. I also changed the filesize to be up to 2^32 bytes, so that you can see what you have to adjust to change the sizes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. Its working almost perfectly except for one small issue. Sometimes when I connect the client to the server it transfers all the files without any problem but sometimes it transfers like 2 files and then sends junk values as the first size to the server so when it tries to take int of that It gives an error. The buffer leaks somehow. Any idea why?

Comment: So, how big are your files? It will crash for files greater than 4GB with certainty ;] Also, the shown code is just a suggestion and should be interpreted as an example. If you really want to implement file transfer then you might want to build something more robust. If it is not for learning purposes, then it would be a good idea to look at existing protocols. For example, use ssh (paramiko http://www.paramiko.org/) or ftp.

Comment: I just did a copy past on my VM of this code and I got thie error message : "Waiting for a connection.....
Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34836)
File received successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    size = int(size, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '101.py\n    chmod'"  And I receive a file this is not complete...

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple sockets and write using makefile:

server:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

serversock = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9000
serversock.bind((host, port))

serversock.listen(10)
print("Waiting for a connection.....")


def reader(client):
    fle = client.makefile('r')
    filename = fle.readline()
    client.send("Got file {}\n".format(filename))
    file_to_write = open(filename.rstrip(), 'wb')
    client.send("Starting writing {}\n".format(filename))
    file_to_write.write(fle.read())
    file_to_write.close()
    client.send("Finished writing {}\n".format(filename))


while True:
    client, addr = serversock.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    client_serve_thread = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=tuple((client,)))
    client_serve_thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.001)

serversock.close()
```

client:

```
import socket
import os
import thread
import os

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9000

path = "/home/padraic/t"
directory = os.listdir(path)
for file in directory:
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    s.send(file+"\n")
    print(s.recv(1024))
    file_to_send = open(os.path.join(path, file), 'rb')
    s.send(file_to_send.read())
    print('File Sent\n')
    file_to_send.close()
    rec = s.recv(1024)
    print(rec)
    s.close()
```

Comment: I tried but with this its not even connecting to the server :/
This is what the client says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machi
ne actively refused it

Comment: @FahadCheema,  that is because I had  two different port numbers ;) It will work now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're actually receiving all the files' content but then writing them all to one file.

Your server is only accepting a single connection and it writes whatever data it receives into the file until it receives no more data. That won't happen until the client closes its socket at the end.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.

1. Move the `accept` call into the server loop and the `connect` call into the client loop. Have your client connect, send the filename, transfer the entire content of a single file, then *close* the connection. On the next iteration, do it all over again.
2. Alternatively, at the beginning of each file, have the client send to the server both the filename to be transferred and the file size (so the server knows how to find the end of the file content). Then write exactly that many bytes to the server. (But see also below as to transmitting the file size.)

I would recommend (1) as more robust and easier to implement.

Second subject: your mechanism for sending the filename is flawed. If I follow it correctly, your program would not work properly if the filename being transmitted begins with a digit as the server will not be able to determine how many bytes are being used to send the filename length. There are two usual ways of sending numbers:

1. Use the `struct` module to format a binary integer in a well-defined way. You actually send the "packed" format, and the server would unpack it. It would then know exactly how many bytes long to receive for the filename.
2. Just send a header line containing the filename followed by a null byte or newline (or some other well-defined defined terminator byte). Then the server can read a byte at a time of the filename until it sees the terminator.