# Python socket binary formatting issue

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi 3 with a PiCam takes a photo every 10 seconds and sends it to a remote computer over a Python `socket`. I have a transmitter and receiver program that I borrowed from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245818/need-to-transfer-multiple-files-from-client-to-server). When I run the code, it sends the first file with no issues, but when it tries to send the second one, I get the following error on the receiving side:

```
Waiting for a connection.....
Got a connection from ('10.10.10.10', 46490)
File received successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/PhotoSaver/downloadPhotos.py", line 19, in <module>
    size = int(size, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0\xc3\xa8\x0f \xb0\x19\xc3d\xa3\x00\x00\xf9\x80\xcf9'
```

Here is the transmitting code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
class sendPhotos(object):
    def __init__(self, host="10.10.10.17"):
        self.host = host
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        import socket
        import os
        import thread
        from time import sleep, time
        from picamera import PiCamera
        camera = PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
        camera.start_preview()
        #print "Warming up camera"
        sleep(2)
        #print "Camera started"
        s = socket.socket()
        host = self.host
        #host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 9000
        s.connect((host, port))

        while True:
            filename = str(int(time())) + ".jpg"
            camera.capture(filename)#Capture image with name as current time

            size = len(filename)
        size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) # encode filename size as 16 bit binary
        s.send(size)
        s.send(filename)

        filename = os.path.join(path,filename)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        filesize = bin(filesize)[2:].zfill(32) # encode filesize as 32 bit binary
        s.send(filesize)

        file_to_send = open(filename, 'rb')

        l = file_to_send.read()
        s.sendall(l)
        file_to_send.close()
        print 'File Sent'
            os.system("sudo rm " + filename)
            sleep(10)
s.close()
```

Here is the receiving code:

```
import socket import thread import hashlib

serversock = socket.socket() host = "" port = 9000; serversock.bind((host,port)); filename = "" serversock.listen(10); print "Waiting for a connection....."

clientsocket,addr = serversock.accept() print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr)) while True:
    size = clientsocket.recv(16) # Note that you limit your filename length to 255 bytes.
    if not size:
        break
    size = int(size, 2)
    filename = clientsocket.recv(size)
    filesize = clientsocket.recv(32)
    filesize = int(filesize, 2)
    file_to_write = open(filename, 'wb')
    chunksize = 4096
    while filesize > 0:
        if filesize < chunksize:
            chunksize = filesize
        data = clientsocket.recv(chunksize)
        file_to_write.write(data)
        filesize -= chunksize

    file_to_write.close()
    print 'File received successfully' serversock.close()
```

Any idea as to what is causing this?
Thanks,

UPDATE:
In the transmitting code, size, an int, is formatted and sent as below:

```
size = len(filename)
size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) # encode filename size as 16 bit binary
s.send(size)
```

When it is printed with repr(), it comes out as: `0\xc3\xa8\x0f \xb0\x19\xc3d\xa3\x00\x00\xf9\x80\xcf9` 
It appears to me that it is some issue with formatting for the socket and decoding, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "invalid literal for int() with base 2". This Exception appears to be telling you that the variable 'size' contains an invalid binary value. (Binary is base 2). Try using some 'print debugging' to see the value of 'size' at various key points until you catch the offending value and its cause

Comment: I looked into that in the update to my post and found it is likely a formatting with regards to the socket. Any ideas as to how it is changing during the socket transmission and reception?

Comment: len(filename) should be an int.. and the you turn size into a 16bit binary value... where is the hex coming from? Is that what you are asking me? I really don't know. If this is python 3 we are dealing with, everything sent on the socket should be sent as a bytes object...